Dynamic Cropping of Video Files in React Native with IMG.LY's VideoEditor SDK
I'm working on a React Native camera app within the Expo Framework (managed workflow) and need some assistance with functionalities and capabilities of the VideoEditor SDK by IMG.LY.
Expectations:
Ultimately, I aim to achieve the following functionalities with my app:

Produce a portrait version immediately after filming stops:
The application needs to capture a video in one orientation (landscape) and quickly create another video in the opposite orientation (portrait) post-recording.

Track a target object in portrait mode while filming in landscape:
The user must be able to dynamically move within the 'portrait crop zone' in the landscape viewport, which tracks and captures the target scene, enhancing the user experience of 'simultaneously filming in both orientations'.


What I've tried:

Attempted to move the crop zone around

What I expected to happen:

The new video depicts the scene using new and dynamic positions of the viewport.

What actually resulted:

Viewport remains fixed on the final position of the crop zone

Challenges:
While I can use the VideoEditor SDK to crop the video post-recording, the new viewport ("crop zone") remains stationary throughout the entire video, even if the target moves out of the crop zone. When I attempt to dynamically move the crop zone to capture the target's position, the saved file always shows the viewport at the final position of the crop zone throughout the video, instead of tracking the target as intended.
My dog (target of interest) goes out of the new viewport
Inquiries:

Dynamic Cropping of Video Files: Does the VideoEditor SDK support dynamic cropping of a video file? Specifically, can the editor transform specific parts of the video into a portrait size with a moving 'portrait zone' directed by the user?

Coordinate-Based Cropping: If dynamic cropping is supported, can I provide specific coordinate values for cropping along with the relevant time (in seconds or smaller)? Can the editor dynamically transform the video using these values?

Required Data and Format: If coordinate-based dynamic cropping is possible, what specific data do I need to provide to the SDK, and in what format should this information be provided?

Cropping Engineering: For clarification, does anyone know whether the cropping transformation occur directly at the video level or frame by frame?

Pricing: Does anyone know how IMG.LY's pricing model work? Is it subscription-based or based on usage? The above development was done during the trial period.


Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to your responses.

You have some interesting requirements that you'd like to add to the img.ly SDK. However, based on my research and development, it seems that img.ly doesn't currently offer these features.
I've looked into the img.ly SDK as well as other SDKs like Banuba and Meishe, but it appears they don't provide the exact functionalities you're seeking.
I believe you might need to delve into machine learning for object detection and explore other SDKs that can create portrait versions from landscape recordings simultaneously.
